# Access registry of Windows XP from Windows 7 in same local machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

How to access all registry keys of Windows XP from Windows 7, if both OS are installed in same local machine?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Regedit
2. File -> Load Hive
3. Browse to the Windows XP hive files (`<XPDrive>\Windows\system32\config\` - `SAM`, `SECURITY`, `SYSTEM`, `SOFTWARE`) and load each one.